# create js array dynamically?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dynamic

how could I declare several js array dynamically? 
For example, here is what tried but failed:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 for (i=0;i<10;i++)
 {
   var "arr_"+i = new Array();
 }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You were pretty close depending on what you would like to do..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var w = window;
     for (i=0;i<10;i++)
     {
       w["arr_"+i] = [];
     }
</script>
```

Would work, what is your intention for use though?

Comment: @Tim Whitlock Perhaps you could elaborate on your statement and completely explain scope and preferred JS programming techniques to the OP for his simple question.

Comment: Yes, and explain how you can write any program with zero globals.

Answer (score 5):

make it an array of arrays:

```
var arr = [];  // creates a new array .. much preferred method too.
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    arr[i] = [];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put them all into an array, like this...

```
var arrContainer = [];

 for (i=0;i<10;i++)
 {
   arrContainer.push(new Array());
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `[...new Array(10)]`. It is short and handy.